# How to generate a Sceneform asset at runtime in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, arcore, sceneform, 3d-model

I am new to flutter and am currently developing a AR based application. I want to create renderable 3d Sceneform assets at RUNTIME. I know how to define a Sceneform asset in the build.gradle file but that isn't dynamic.

The way to make a 3d sceneform asset in the compilation(app level build.gradle):

```
sceneform.asset('sampledata/earth.obj',
        'default',
        'sampledata/earth.sfa',
        'src/main/assets/earth_model')
```

But I want to create a sceneform asset during runtime. I am using [arcore_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin) and Google's AR core with sceneform. I am unable to find any assistance/examples to render a 3d sceneform asset at runtime from firebase storage in flutter. All of the documentations available are for java and kotlin. The purpose of rendering sceneform assets at runtime is to load a .sfb file from [firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) and render it in the app to keep the app lightweight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dig deep into the documentation docs, you will find class `ArCoreReferenceNode` with parameter `objectUrl`
https://pub.dev/documentation/arcore_flutter_plugin/latest/arcore_flutter_plugin/ArCoreReferenceNode/objectUrl.html.

I will take from the [example app code](https://github.com/giandifra/arcore_flutter_plugin/blob/master/example/lib/screens/remote_object.dart#L35-L44)

```
final toucanNode = ArCoreReferenceNode(
    name: "Toucano",
    objectUrl:
            "https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/raw/master/2.0/Duck/glTF/Duck.gltf",
    position: plane.pose.translation,
    rotation: plane.pose.rotation,
);

arCoreController.addArCoreNodeWithAnchor(toucanNode);
```

Comment: Bro thanks it worked, now is there any service i can use to host .gltf files. The original thought process was to download a .obj from firebase storage, but your answer made it waaaay easier.

Comment: It depends on your need about storage and bandwith. But netlify.com is good enough for me. It can deploy right from your git :) sometime I deploy it on github gh page

Comment: btw, is there a way i can scan and render in arcore? checkout this vid to understand, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWzurBQ81CM

Also bro you from android ville?

Comment: Never try it before, maybe someday. I'm not from android ville too btw